# How to calculate fare

Tags: dictionary, graph, graph-theory

like Ola, Uber etc. how they calculate fare
Example when I start from one point  to another   (like 1 to 2km) shows amount that is 40 rs
how they calculate use map distance  in code or something else in code can u please explain how it work? Simply how it works fare system works?

Answer (score 0):

This is lifted directly from the Uber website:

> Many data points go into calculating an upfront price, including the
> estimated trip time, distance from origin to destination, time of day,
> route, and demand patterns. It also includes tolls, taxes, surcharges,
> and fees (with the exception of wait time fees).

> Some cities do not provide upfront prices. Instead, you’re charged
> either a minimum price or a price based on the time and distance for
> your trip’s route, which may include a base fare, a Booking Fee,
> surcharges, tolls, and dynamic pricing. Prices may vary by location,
> the vehicle option you select, and other factors.

So it sounds like a combination of any relevant data points your app is able to collect and that you feel should be considered billable are applied to the calculation. I imagine you would want to use the map distance rather than a predefined route in case of detours, traffic, etc.